# How can i set the properties of button kept in the item template of DataList on run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i set the properties of button kept in the item template of DataList on run time.
i need to apply setting for the buttons from the database button setting.

```
<asp:DataList ID="btnDataList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                    RepeatColumns="4" onitemcreated="btnDataList_ItemCreated">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="itemBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

i need to apply setn for the button like width, height, font color, type, etc on fyl

Comment: Why are you not applying the attributes using the OnItemCreated or When the item is databound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
       // Retrieve the Button control in the current DataListItem.
       Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("ItemBtn");

       //Then set the buttons properties over here
     }
   }
```